# unix shell globbing binding

Tags: bash, unix, shell

If i have a do loop that looks something like

```
for file in *txt; do {something on $file that results in another file ending with txt being created}; done
```

Will that cause an infinite loop?  I'm rather afraid to test it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The expansion of `*.txt` is typically done by the shell before any commands are run. So, no, it won't result in an infinite loop.

I say "typically" since it depends, of course, on the shell you're using. But every shell I've had experience with works this way, including `bash` as shown below:

```
pax$ rm -rf *.xyzzy ; touch 1.xyzzy 2.xyzzy ; ls *.xyzzy
1.xyzzy  2.xyzzy

pax$ echo ===== ; for i in *.xyzzy ; do
>    echo Processing $i
>    echo ..... before touch ; ls *.xyzzy
>    touch 3.xyzzy
>    echo ..... after touch ; ls *.xyzzy
>    echo =====
> done
=====
Processing 1.xyzzy
..... before touch
1.xyzzy  2.xyzzy
..... after touch
1.xyzzy  2.xyzzy  3.xyzzy
=====
Processing 2.xyzzy
..... before touch
1.xyzzy  2.xyzzy  3.xyzzy
..... after touch
1.xyzzy  2.xyzzy  3.xyzzy
=====

pax$ ls *.xyzzy
1.xyzzy  2.xyzzy  3.xyzzy
```

You'll note that the `3` file added during the first loop iteration *doesn't* affect the loop at all, because the expansion has already been done at that point.

Comment: This is also true in C shell. `foreach i (*.xyzzy) ... end` gives the same results as bash.

Answer (score 0):

No infinite loop is created because the glob expansion is done before the loop contents are handled.

If you ever want to try out something like this, check out [ulimits](http://ss64.com/bash/ulimit.html) and setup a conservative buffer of CPU time and processes to test with.